# Some help on this question about stochastic epidemic models without removals would be greatly appreciated

Tags: mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution, epidemiology

I get this question up until the underlined part, would someone be able to explain the rest of it to me as its had me stumped for a little while now.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the underlined expression, the next expression is obtained by writing $\frac{1}{i(n-i)}$ as a partial fraction decomposition $\frac{A}{i}+\frac{B}{n-i}$ for some $A$, $B$. The next expression after that is obtained by observing that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n-i}$. Finally, we use the fact that the harmonic numbers $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i}$ grow roughly as $\log(n)$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n) for more information).